# $55$ gangsters shoot the nearest gangster to them, where all the distances between them are different. Prove that at least one gangster will survive.

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

My thinking was that if gangster A shoots gangster B, then gangster B will also shoot gangster A since they are the closest together, forming a pair. Since 55 is odd, then one must survive since 55 is 1 mod 2.

P.S The question assumes the following :

> 1. If distance from any gangster A to any gangster B is x then distance from gangster B to gangster A is also x.
> 2. No gangster commits suicide.

Comment: Not necessarily true. Place three gangsters, A, B, and C, collinearly with B between A and C and B closer to C. A shoots B but B doesn't shoot A, meaning that your reasoning is false.

Comment: This must be my stupidest comment but if $A$ shoots $B$, how can $B$ also shoot $A$? Dead men with guns? Especially as the question is related to survival. Or did I miss a key piece of information?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I think the shootings are going to happen instantaneously

Comment: So it was my stupidest comment after all.

Comment: So these gangsters, they are synchronized to millisecond precision? Now that's what I call *organized crime*.

Comment: I think shooting as a cycle is not possible because say there are $3$ gangsters $g_1$, $g_2$ and $g_3$. And suppose the distance between $g_1$ and $g_2$ is $x$, $g_2$ and $g_3$ is $y$ and $g_1$ and $g_3$ is $z$. Now, if $g_1$ shoots $g_2$, then $x < z$. If $g_2$ shoots $g_3$, $y < x$ and if $g_3$ shoots $g_1$, $z < y$. Contradiction.

Comment: Are gangsters living in three dimensional space?

Comment: Seems to me that the closest gangster to each gangster is going to be that same gangster. We'll see 55 suicides and no survivor.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The pair of gangsters with lowest pairwise distance will shoot each other. If some other gangster shoots any of those two, then there will be at most $52$ bullets aimed at the remaining $53$ gangsters, and hence at least one will survive.

If no other gangster shoots any of those two, the problem is reduced to the case of $53$ gangsters and we proceed by induction. At this point, it boils down to checking that the case for $3$ gangsters always ends up with one alive.

Comment: It might be worthy to point out that we can rule out suicide, hence $3$ gansters is the special case, not $1$.

Comment: Even in the case of 3, of the ${3 \choose 2}$ pairs of gangsters, the pair with the shortest distance will shoot each other, so 1 is a valid base case.

Answer (score 11):

We will argue by contradiction. Assume everyone died.

Nobody can shoot the same guy twice since there are only 55 bullets and 55 people to kill.

So, WLOG$^{\ast}$,by renumbering $g_1$ shoots $g_2$, $g_2$ shoots $g_3$, ..., $g_{55}$ shoots $g_1$.

$^\ast$As N.S. noted there there can be different connected components, however since $55$ is odd one them must of length at least 3, or 1.

Denote $l_i$ the distance between $g_i$ and $g_{i+1}$, for $1\leq i\leq 54$ and $l_{55}$ the distance between $g_{55}$ and $g_1$.

Notice that $l_1>l_2$ since $g_2$ shoots $g_3$ and not $g_1$. Similarly $l_i>l_{i+1}$ which leads to a contradiction since $l_1>l_{54}>l_{55}$ and $l_{55}>l_1$.

Comment: You can also get smaller cycles $g_1$ shoots $g_2$ and $g_2$ shoots $g_1$. But at least one cycle is odd.

Comment: @N.S. Right! I assumed the graph was connected.

Comment: Your argument works as long as there is a cycle of length $>2$. And the odd cycle must have lenght at least three (or is a 1-cycle, i.e. survivor).

Comment: @N.S. thanks I included your comment in my answer

Comment: @N.S. Seems to me a 1-cycle is a suicide, not a survivor...

Answer (score 7):

Say $G$ is the set of gansters. Define $s:G\to G$ by saying that $g$ shoots $s(g)$. We need to show $g $ is not surjective.

Suppose $s$ is surjective. Since $G$ is finite it follows that $s$ is injective.

And since $s$ is a bijection, the simple inductive argument in the deleted answer works: Say $d(g_1,g_2)$ is the smallest distance. Them $s(g_1)=g_2$ and $s(g_2)=g_1$. Since $s$ is a bijection on $G$ it follows that $s$ maps $G'=G\setminus\{g_1,g_2\}$ to itself. (This last point was not clear in the deleted answer, which is presumably why it was deleted.) It follows by induction that there exists $g$ with $s(g)=g$.

Of course if each gangster literally shoots the nearest gagnster then $s(g)=g$ for all $g$. But clearly what was intended is that each gangster shoots the nearest *other* gangster, in which case $s(g)=g$ iis a contradiction.

Comment: Dear David, I have taken the liberty to correct a little typo in line 3: you had written $g$ instead of $s$. (And I upvoted your nice solution, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

For each gangster $g_i$ define 
$$M_i= \min \{ d(g_i, g_j) \mid j \neq i \}$$

Since all the distances are different,  $M= \max \{ M_i \}$ is exactly one of these distances, and hence can be attained at most twice.

**Case 1:** $M$ is attained exactly once. Let $i$ be the point where it is reached. Show that $g_i$ survives.

**Case 2:** $M$ is attained exactly twice. Let $i,j$ be the points where it is reached, i.e. $M_i=M_j=M$.

Show that $g_i$ shoots $g_j$, $g_j$ shoots $g_i$ and no other $g_k$ shoots either $g_i$ or $g_j$.

Thus the problem reduces to *53 gangsters shoot the nearest gangster to them, where all the distances between them are different*. As you observed, the number being odd is the key for this reduction (i.e. induction over $n$ odd).

Comment: What is $d(g_i,g_j)$?

Comment: @user477343 This stands for the distance between gangster $i$ and gangster $j$

Comment: @clark I was taught that for some value $x \in \mathbb{Z}, \ d(x) =$ the number of *divisors* of $x$...

Comment: @user477343 $\text{d}(x,y)$ is a common notation, when working in metric spaces, to denote the distance between elements $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @clark ahh, so perhaps $\text{d}(n)$ for some *integer* $m$ would be the number of divisors of $m$, but if we have $\text{d}(n)$ for some *ordered pair* $n$ then this is different. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @user477343 We only have 26 letters and a lot of mathematical definitions. Letters are often used with different meaning in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

As we are given an odd number 55 so, we can prove by taking any odd number. Let us take 5 for easy understating.

So, we have 5 gangsters and they are A, B, C, D and E.

Step 1 : If A shoots B and C shoots D then we are left with 3 gangsters A, C and E.

Step 2: Now its the turn of E. As there us no D so, E is closest to C and it will shoot C. Now we are left with A and E.

Step 3 : There is no one between A and E so, if A shoots E then A would survive.

So, each of 5 gangsters shoot their nearest gangster and one survived.

Similar is the case with 55 gangsters because 55 is also an odd number and if all 55 gangsters shoot their nearest gangster then, one will survive.

Answer (score 0):

If the gangsters shooting other is looked at as a directed graph, then it is impossible for the graph to have a cycle longer than 2.  Because in a path without 2-cycles:
$$G_1 \to G_2 \to G_3 \to \cdots$$

The distances between successive vertices must be decreasing.  So if the cycle has $G_n \to G_1 \to G_2$ , it is saying that $G_1$ shoots $G_2$ despite $G_n$ being closer.

So the head of any path doesn't get shot, unless the path is a 2-cycle.